# Windows Azure Backup suddently failing jobs - Error 100023

Tags: azure, azure-vm-role

The last couple of days Azure Backup has been failing jobs with error **100023**.

> The encryption passphrase stored for this computer is not correctly configured. The encryption passphrase can be configured from the Windows Azure Backup Agent MMC snap-in. In the Action pane, click Properties and then click the Encryption
>   settings tab. Type the passphrase used for encryption of backups in the space provided.

I haven't changed the encryption password or location lately, so this is a bit unexpected.

At first I tought It may be an outage with Azure Backup itself but it's been a couple of days and still I'm getting the same issue.

I have since accessed the Backup Vault panel on manage.windowsazure.com and allowed re-registration for the affected server. However during the re-registration process I'm getting the same error.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Download and update to the latest Azure Backup Agent (MARSAgentInstaller.exe) from the management portal at https://manage.windowsazure.com/

After doing so, try again.

This article can be used as a reference: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/backup-configure-vault/#download-install-and-register-the-azure-backup-agent

The download page should look something like this (Windows Server agent highlighted in red):

[image: Azure agent download from management portal]

Answer (score 0):

1. Install the new agent from the Azure Site.
2. Delete the backup Jobs
3. De-register the server from the Azure Site
4. Uninstall Agent from the server
5. Download new registration certificate
6. Install Agent and point it to the new certificate.
7. Create a backup job and test it.